# I am trying to make an addon that enables the user to animate the influence of the armature modifier

Tags: python, armature

I am wondering wether it is possible since the armature modifier struct doesn't have an influence float input. Neither do any of the other modifiers. It is my goal to have an influence slider just like with constraints (i.e. copy location)

[image]

[image]